# dd^c of log of a meromorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, greens-function, differential-operators

In Atsushi Moriwaki's Arakelov Geometry, page 100, in a discussion about Greens functions, the proof of proposition 4.13 claims that $$dd^c(\log|\phi|)=0$$
for a non-zero rational function $\phi$ on a connected compact Riemann surface. The $dd^c$ operator is given by $$dd^c=\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{2\pi}\partial\bar{\partial}$$
Why is it the case that $dd^c(\log|\phi|)=0$ ?

Comment: HINT: Is $\log |\phi|$ harmonic?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how being harmonic solves this. Is there a way of seeing it in terms of zeros and poles of $\phi$?

Comment: How could zeroes and poles have anything to do with the global behavior of the function? You need to understand what $dd^c = 0$ means.

Comment: $\log|\phi|$ is harmonic away from the zeros and poles of $\phi$. Could you enlighten me as to what $dd^c=0$ means?

Comment: It means harmonic. You probably should either compute $\partial\bar\partial$ in “real” coordinates or compute it on the real part of a holomorphic function.